# jProfiler trigger file location

Tags: triggers, jprofiler

I setup trigger in jProfiler ver. 8.1.4. This trigger should store snapshoot with name "controller_" when CPU is higher than 80% for about 10 seconds. This trigger is active in my session. jProfiler is attached to my project and trigger should be fired several times, but I can not see snapshot from jProfiler.

Where it is located? 
Should I run some recording?

Thank you for quick response.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a relative file name in the "Save snapshot" action, the snapshot will be stored in the working directory of the profiled application.

The trigger system prints error messages to stdout by default. On the "Output" tab of the trigger configuration in the session settings dialog you can choose stderr or a redirection file.

Comment: But I'm using remote profiling. Will this snapshot be stored on this device?

Comment: Yes, the "Save snapshot" action saves the snapshot on the remote machine, not on your local machine.